# C# Преобразование PDF в XPS

Tags: c#, pdf

Мне необходимо программно на C# реализовать преобразования pdf в xps без ограничений по листам, без добавления надписей и бесплатно (без всяких принтеров acrobat). Я пробовал GemBox, Spire, Aspose - прекрасно работают но имеют ограниченный функционал в бесплатной версии. Есть еще какие-нибудь варианты помимо ghostscript.net (оставляю на самую последнюю очередь).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PDFsharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net) похоже на то что ты ищешь.

Просмотри: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848223/wpf-to-xps-to-pdf.

А еще:  https://nathanpjones.com/2013/03/output-to-pdf-in-wpf-for-free/ :

Блок юзингов:

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Packaging;
using System.Windows.Xps.Packaging;
using System.Windows.Xps;
```

Скорее всего будет что-то вроде:

```
PdfSharp.Xps.XpsConverter.Convert(sourcePdfFile, destXpsFile, 0);
```

---

Но стоит заметить что не каждый пдф можно полноценно перевести в икспеес формат ибо многие пдф-ки имеют картинку на всю страницу. Даже если на картинке текст.

Поэтому возможно стоит взглянуть еще в сторону каких-то программ для сканирования и в подобных случаях сканировать пдф в ворд с посдледующим пересохранением в XPS. Но это прийдется делать вручную.

---

Как и раньше - найдено по ключевикам "c# pdf to xps"

Comment: Aspose имеет существенные ограничения в бесплатной версии, я его пробовал и написал об этом

Comment: проапдейтил. Нашел вместо тебя по тем же ключевикам которые были указаны раньше.